# Agregar String con multineas a una lista Java

Tags: java, string

tengo la siguiente duda, como puedo agregar un string que viene con la siguiente estructura en una lista de string

```
String unaLinea = "123456789101121314151161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839041424344454647484950";
    
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < unaLinea.length(); i++) {
    if (i > 0 && (i % 10 == 0)) {
        sb.append("\n");
    
    }

    sb.append(unaLinea.charAt(i));
}

unaLinea = sb.toString();
System.out.println(unaLinea);
```

Salida

```
1234567891
0112131415
1161718192
0212223242
5262728293
0313233343
5363738390
4142434445
4647484950
```

Todo eso esta dentro del String, y mi duda es como agregarlo como si cada linea fuese un elemento por separado en una lista de String

```
List<String> listaElementos = new ArrayList<>();
```

para que asi luego la lista tenga X cantidad de elementos y no solo 1 con todo el String, ya que si hago un

```
listaElementos.add(unaLinea);
```

Solo tendre 1 unico indice con toda la informacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que tienes la string separada por \n, tal vez podrías separar la cadena con String.split("\n") y la recibirías en un arreglo, algo como esto:

```
String[] parts = unalinea.split("\n");
```

y luego podrías pasar ese arreglo a una lista:

```
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList(parts);
```

Bueno, podrías intentar

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String unaLinea = "123456789101121314151161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839041424344454647484950";

        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < unaLinea.length(); i = i +10){
            lista.add(unaLinea.substring(i, i+10));
        }
        
        lista.stream().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
    }
```

Comment: Una explicación no caería mal amigo